# Listing everything in a UNC path telling me that the path cannot be found

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7, unc

I'm connecting to a UNC path using `win_unc`:

```
import win_unc as unc

def list_all_printers_on_server(servername):
    creds = unc.UncCredentials(r"<USER>", "<PASS>")
    authz_unc = unc.UncDirectory(servername, creds=creds)
    conn = unc.UncDirectoryConnection(authz_unc)
    conn.connect()
    if conn.is_connected():
        print "connected"
        print conn.get_connection_status()
        print conn.get_path()
    else:
        print "not connected "
        print conn.connect()
```

I'm able to get it connected and print the path and such, but what I want to do is print everything in the UNC path. If I use `os.listdir()` I get the following error:

```
connected
ok
\\<UNC>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fdap.py", line 504, in <module>
    list_all_printers_on_server(r"\\<UNC>")
  File "fdap.py", line 471, in list_all_printers_on_server
    os.listdir(servername)
WindowsError: [Error 67] The network name cannot be found: '<UNC>/*.*'
```

Now I don't understand why it is telling me that the path cannot be found when it tells me that the connection status is `ok`, how can I connect to this path and list everything inside of it?

Comment: Try connecting with `net.exe` instead, e.g. `import subprocess;` `cmd = r'net use "\\{}\{}" /user:{} {}'.format(servername, sharename, username, password);` `subprocess.call(cmd)`.

Comment: I'm not sure you can enumerate printers that way.  What happens on the command line if you type this command: `dir \\<UNC>` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, if it were `\\server\printshare` for a valid printer share, I'd expect a file not found error. I thought it might be the `print$` share with the drivers.

Comment: @eryksun, that's possible too.  My guess was that the OP was trying to list the contents of `\\servername` since if you do that in Explorer for a typical print server it shows you a list of printers.  But there are a number of possible variants, it's hard to tell without seeing the code and/or uncensored output.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, your intuition is probably right. It didn't occur to me that someone would try to list `\\server` based on what Explorer shows them. In that case Python appends `/*.*` and the user-mode RTL converts it to `\??\UNC\server\*.*`, but without identifying `"*.*"` as the filename part since that component is expected to be the share name. Thus `FindFirstFile` passes that path as is to `NtOpenFile`, and predictably MUP returns the status code `STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME`.

Comment: @eryksun You are correct it is the print server where the printers and drivers are, and I was indeed trying to list all the printers that are shown in explorer, with python. Having read over what you guys said, I'm assuming there's no way to do this?

Comment: @oaq25955, you can list printer shares, but not using filesystem directory functions. For example: `[s for s in win32net.NetShareEnum(server, 1)[0] if s['type'] & win32netcon.STYPE_PRINTQ]`. See [`NetShareEnum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387) and the [`win32net`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32net.html) docs.

Comment: `NetShareEnum` is implemented by making an RPC call to the LanmanServer service. You can set a breakpoint on `srvsvc!NetrShareEnum` in its svchost.exe host process to see the LanmanServer service make an `NtFsControlFile` (file-system control) system call to `\Device\SrvAdmin` to query the share enumeration.